# Qual è il senso di "qualunque" in questo verso del Paradiso?

Tags: word-meaning, pronouns

Ecco alcune terzine del canto XXXI del *Paradiso* di Dante (versi dal 73 al 78, grassetto mio):

> Da quella regïon che più sù tona 
>           occhio mortale alcun tanto non dista, 
>          
> **qualunque** in mare più giù s’abbandona,
>          
> quanto lì da Beatrice la mia vista;
>          
> ma nulla mi facea, ché süa effige
>          
> non discendëa a me per mezzo mista.

La mia domanda è sul senso del termine "qualunque" nel verso 75. Leggendo le diverse accezioni che appaiono sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00060.jpg), anche [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00061.jpg), ho pensato fosse "qualsiasi persona che", ma non ne sono per niente sicura. Anzi, ho l'impressione che mi sfugga qualche sfumatura.

Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire questo mio dubbio?

Answer (score 1):

In questo passaggio "qualunque" è da intendersi come "neppure quello che / anche se / per quanto"; la parafrasi è grossomodo:

> Nessun occhio mortale è più distante
> da quella regione di cielo in cui tuona,
> **neppure quello che** / **anche se** / **per quanto** si inabissasse nel mare più profondo,
> Di quanto (era distante) da Beatrice la mia vista;
> ma (questa distanza) non aveva alcun effetto, poiché la sua figura
> non arrivava a me attraversando un mezzo fisico

O, in forma un po' più libera:

> [73-75] Nessun occhio mortale, **anche se** guardasse dal più profondo del mare, disterebbe da quella regione più alta dell’aria nella quale si formano i tuoni,
> [76-78] più di quanto la mia vista lì distava da Beatrice; ma ciò non mi era di alcun ostacolo, perché la sua immagine non giungeva a me velata dall’atmosfera.

[EDIT] Probabilmente la parafrasi più "aderente" sarebbe [**quantunque**](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quantunque/), anche se nell'italiano quotidiano moderno è poco usato